# Return an object after parsing xml with SAX

Tags: python, xml, sax

I have some large XML files to parse and have created an object class to contain my relevant data.  Unfortunately, I am unsure how to return the object for later processing.  Right now I pickle my data and moments later depickle the object for access.  This seems wasteful, and there surely must be a way of grabbing my data without hitting the disk.

```
def endElement(self, name):
    if name == "info": # done collecting this iteration
        self.data.setX(self.x)
        self.data.setY(self.y)
    elif name == "lastTagOfInterest": # done with file
        # want to return my object from here
        filehandler = open(self.outputname + ".pi", "w")
        pickle.dump(self.data, filehandler)
        filehandler.close()
```

I have tried putting a return statement in my endElement tag, but that does not seem to get passed up the chain to where I call the SAX parser.

Thanks for any tips.

Comment: Isn't it in self.data ? Is there something I don't get ?

Comment: Correct, I was blinded by temporary stupidity.

Answer (score 2):

Bah, sat and thought about it for a second and the answer was obvious.  Return quit the method, and then just pull out the data field from the ContentHandler object I had created.

Comment: I'm trying to solve the same problem and every single tutorial ends in printing the extracted data, not working with them further. Having a dataclass attribute that I can extract from handler was my idea as well, but it feels like hacking. I'd expect to get some output from parser. Is there really no cleaner way to get parsed object?